# value = 0 while other line items > 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to know how to write a query where unique IDs with multiple line items will have 1 line item with a particular code, let's call it A4445, where charge amount is = 0, while all the other lines with other codes other than A4445 linked to that ID would be greater than 0 like the following. If the data looked like this:

```
   ID    | line item |  code  | Charge |
---------+-----------+--------+---------
 3334400 |     1     | A4445  | 32.50  |
 3334400 |     2     | B0021  |  0.00  | 
 3334400 |     3     | B0666  |  9.00  |
```

but I want IDs that have the A4445 code = 0.00 and the other lines with a charge amount greater > 0

```
   ID    | line item |  code  | Charge |
---------+-----------+--------+---------
 3334422 |     1     | A4445  |  0.00  |
 3334422 |     2     | B0021  | 12.30  | 
 3334422 |     3     | B0666  |  9.00  |
```

I'm currently using the union all function but I don't think it's working. This is my query:

```
Select 
       ID,
       Line item,
       Code,
       Charge    
from   
       claim    
where 
       code = 'A4445'
and    charge = 0.00

union all

Select 
       ID,
       Line item,
       Code,
       Charge    
from  
       claim    
where 
       code <> 'A4445'
and    charge > 0.00
```

I'm not sure how to articulate this but hopefully the above illustration will give you an idea of what I'm looking for

Comment: is the `A4445` a hardcoded thing ? Also don't quite understand your second condition about `A4445 code = 0.00`. Please elaborate

Comment: @Squirrel yes the A4445 code is obligatory. I want IDs that have the A4445 code equal charge of 0.00 but I want the other lines attached to the ID not to equal 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
select c.id
from claim c
group by c.id
having max(case when c.code = 'A4445' then c.charge end) = 0 and
       min(case when c.code <> 'A4445' then c.charge end) > 0;
```

This assumes that `charge` is never negative (you have no such examples in your data).  It is easy enough to support negative charges, but the logic is a little bit more complicated.

If  you want the original rows, you can use this with `join`, `exists`, or `in` to get those values.  However, I would probably use `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from claims c
where not exists (select 1
                  from claims c2
                  where c2.id = c.id and c2.code = 'A4445' and c2.charge <> 0
                 ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from claims c2
                  where c2.id = c.id and c2.code <> 'A4445' and c2.charge = 0
                 );
```

Comment: what is the purpose of "select 1"?

Comment: @user9637230 . . . `not exists` only cares about rows being returned.  I find that "1" is the simplest thing to type.